# Unity - Steel Series Nimbus Input

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, input, controller

I am trying to use my Steel Series Nimbus as a wireless remote for my iOS game but I can't get the input to work. The left and right stick work just fine but none of the buttons, triggers or bumpers work at all. I think it is something to do with my Input Manager Settings. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated if you could give me an answer.

Many Thanks,

Tommy :)

Comment: Can you please share the `KeyCode`s you discovered for the Nimbus? I'm still unable to read from the buttons of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but none of the buttons, triggers or bumpers work at all. I think it
>   is something to do with my Input Manager Settings.

Maybe you are not reading them correctly? Use the code below to find out all the Steel Series Nimbus Joystick button `KeyCodes` then use the `KeyCode` to detect when the Button is pressed.

Simply connect the Controller, Create simple `Text` on the screen then drag it to the `text` slot. Build and Run. While running, press buttons on the controller and write down their `KeyCodes`. These `KeyCodes` you should then use to properly detect button that is pressed later on. You can learn more about iOS controller [support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-joystick.html) here.

```
public class KeyCodeFinder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;

    Array allKeyCodes;

    void Start()
    {
        allKeyCodes = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        foreach (KeyCode tempKey in allKeyCodes)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(tempKey))
            {
                text.text = "Pressed: KeyCode." + tempKey;
                Debug.Log("Pressed: KeyCode." + tempKey);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but it doesn't seem to work. I get an error saying  cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Array' to 'UnityEngine.KeyCode[]'

Comment: (By the way this is C#)

Comment: The code I posted above is in C#. that's what I use to solve problems like this one. I even copied it directly to Visual Studio right now and it works. No error or what so ever. This is a very simple answer that should work without modification. Copy it directly to make sure that you are not missing anything. Remember to include `using System` at the top.

Comment: I have done. It does not recognise array for some reason.

Comment: How about this? Copy the whole code for that and put paste it at https://justpaste.it/ . I will take a look at it

Comment: I have fixed the errors with the script but still nothing comes up in neither the console nor the text box. Here is the link https://justpaste.it/yybo

Comment: First, you complained there is an error. Now you say it doesn't even work.  You have to attach the script to a GameObject(Maybe an empty GameObject). Run it then press a key on your keybaord. It should show you the name of the keycode on the screen and in the Log tab. Does that happen?

Comment: Yes it works with keys on my keyboard but I'm looking for something that works with my joystick. I want it to show me the key code for my joystick input

Comment: I know. It has to work with keyboard before it can with the controller. Connect the controller then try it. Press every Button

Comment: Ok. It works with the keyboard but not with the controller. I have tried every single button.

Comment: I have just tried a different controller and the buttons work. However the triggers do not. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I am confused. Buttons work but triggers does not? Buttons are now working on your `Steel Series Nimbus` controller or another controller?

Comment: My steel series nimbus controller returns nothing. Instead I tried using my Xbox360 controller. My Xbox360 controller returns the keycode for buttons but not for triggers.

Comment: Ok that makes sense now. What platform are you doing the test on right now?

Comment: Ok. Build it and run it then test it. Build the Project then let me know if you see the keycode on the text.

Comment: Ok will do. I'll reply once I have tested it.

Comment: Hi again, It's all working now thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Nice. This can be used to get any controller working. You are welcome and happy coding!

Comment: @TommyEaves I'm having the same problem. The `KeyCodeFinder` script works as expected, for keyboards and other controllers, but nothing for the Nimbus, neither in the Unity editor nor a build. Can you think of anything you did besides build the project to make the Nimbus fire key codes for the buttons? The Nimbus axes work as expected, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

It wont work unless you are testing your build directly on Apple tv or an iOS device.

I made a test scene that detects the joystick button 0  and so on and I can confirm this are the numbers for the keys for the nimbus.
I will help you out by writting them down here :)

Joysticks axis
Joystick Left   X axis, Y axis
Joystick Right X 3rd axis,  Y is 4th axis

Dpad
UP _ joystick button 4
LEFT _ joystick button 7
DOWN _ joystick button 6
RIGHT _ joystick button 5

L1  _ joystick button 8
L2 _ joystick button 10

R1 _ joystick button 9
R2_ joystick button 11

X_ joystick button 15
Y_ joystick button 12
A_ joystick button 14
B _ joystick button 13  // careful this is back button on apple tv and returns to dashboard

Menu center button _ joystick button 0

I am trying to figure out how to make menu and B buttons not take you out of the app

Comment: Wait, already fixed to Cancel any type of button going back to Menu, On  Xcode just find the file UnityAppController (ViewHandling)  and on the lien that says
controller.controllerUserInteractionEnabled = NO;                               Equal it to NO as shown here, that will block the going to menu from controllers, remote still working normal.