# Samsung Gear controlls - Unity 3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, samsung-gear

I use Unity 3D with Samsung Gear. I have a working OVRPlayerController in my scene but I am having difficulties mapping the oculus tap, swipe and return button.

I have tried with something like:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))      
{            
   Debug.Log("input detected");
}
```

And with this I detect the tap encircled in red [image]

I have tried also something like:

```
if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryThumbstick))
    {            
        Debug.Log("Input detected");
    }
```

Or :

```
if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.One))
    {
        Debug.Log("Input detected");
    }
```

But nothing seems to work. Is there any documentation that explains how is the input mapped on Samsung Gear that I encircled in yellow ? Does anyone have experience with this or can maybe guide me to some useful documentation on this matter ?

Cheers

My project settings for input:

[image]

Comment: Since `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` is  working for a tap, `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)` should work for the return button. As for swiping, you use `Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X");` and `Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y")`.

Comment: @Programmer - You were right about the return button. Thanks. But about the "swipes" - arrows they don`t seem to work even with Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") or "Mouse X".

Comment: When you import the Oculus SDK, override the `projectsettings` with the one that comes with the `projectsettings`. I think that one contains mapping information about the Axis that will get it working. If this does not work let me know. I have one more possible solution.

Comment: @Programmer - Check the image I added to the question. If you mean about this project settings you can see that I have these defined. I tried something like Input.GetAxis ("Oculus_GearVR_LThumbstickX") but no luck.

Comment: Why not try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39819973/3785314)? It will help you detect which key is being pressed

Comment: @Programmer I will try this Sunday because the gear is not with me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

For swipes, you can get the current `Vector2` on the touchpad (either the HMD and/or the incoming remote controller touchpad) by using:

```
CurrentVector = OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Axis2D.PrimaryTouchpad);
```

as for the back button, it is accessible using `OVRInput.Button.Back` either on `Get`, `GetDown` or `GetUp`. But know that a 2 seconds long back press is reserved for the Universal Menu and should not have any implications inside your game or app.